# How to set output filenames when archiving in split parts using 7zip

Tags: 7zip

I'm using `7zip` to archive and split large files into several volumes.
For example, if I archive `large_file.txt` I get `large_file.txt.7z.001` `large_file.txt.7z.002 ; ...`

I wonder if it is possible to change the output filenames format to have something like this :
`"large_file.txt001.7z" ; "large_file.txt002.7z" ; ...`

I'm looking for a solution that can be used from the GUI if possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, that's not possible. The volumes separately are not 7z files, and the sequence number in the extension is how 7z knows the order in which they should be extracted. Why would you need to do this anyway? The files are of no use to anyone until they're combined.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you very much for your answer! I have to acknowledge this is a pretty weird way to name the volumes but it is the only accepted format for a tool I use frequently.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm archiving many files. It would be good if 7zip divide the files so that the limit is not exceeded for each archive. Some archives could be smaller.

Comment: @Gunslinger: That's not how zip file spanning works. It was originally designed for splitting a large zip file over multiple floppy disks, and each file (except the last) is sized to fill a single disk. It was frequently used in conjunction with self-extracting zip files (executables that extracted the zip contents).

Comment: @KenWhite yes, I discovered that. But you wondered why anyone would want that. I needed to have a large file-set split into several independent archives for uploading to a service that only took real zip-files.

Comment: @Gunslinger: Then zip file spanning isn't what you want. Again, it is designed to **split one single large zip file into multiple pieces that will copy onto individual floppy disks**. The files are useless individually, as each is an incomplete portion of a single zip file - they need to be recombined in the proper order in order to be a valid zip file that can be extracted. If you need something other than that, then do something other than using the built-in file splitting functionality.